# How do I render D3 with D3-force in Meteor-React setting?

Tags: css, reactjs, d3.js, meteor, svg

I'm trying to place [this](https://bl.ocks.org/vasturiano/2992bcb530bc2d64519c5b25201492fd) behind my login box. The svg element is rendering but none of the contents. The rest of the login screen as well as the rest of the website works as expected. Even when I comment out all of the other html and JSX code, the svg doesn't render the particles within it. I even have another D3 element (just a graph) rendering just fine, so I suspect that there's an issue with D3-force. I have the latest d3 and d3-force installed from npm.

Here's all the relevant CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: $base-font-size;
  //background-color: $grey;
}

.boxed-view {
  align-items: center;
  background: $boxed-view-overlay-bg;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.boxed-view__box {
  background-color: $boxed-view-bg;
  margin-bottom: $space;
  padding: 2.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 28rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

And here's all the relevant JS:

```
import d3 from 'd3';
import React from 'react';
import d3_force from 'd3-force';
import {Session} from 'meteor/session';
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker';

import {Bodies} from '../api/bodies';

export default class BrownianSplash extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bodies: [],
      isOpen_add: false,
      isOpen_view: false,
      error: ''
    };
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    let username = this.refs.username.value.trim();
    let password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent page refresh
    Meteor.loginWithPassword({username}, password, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Login callback', err);
        this.setState({error: err.reason});
      } else {
        this.setState({error: ''});
      }
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.bodyNamesTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe('bodies_names');
      const bodies = Bodies.find({}).fetch();
      this.setState({bodies});
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.bodyNamesTracker.stop(); // we don't want to set the state every time the page is loaded
  }
  renderAnimation() {
    const INIT_DENSITY = 0.00025, // particles per sq px
      PARTICLE_RADIUS_RANGE = [1, 12],
      PARTICLE_VELOCITY_RANGE = [0, 4];

    const canvasWidth = window.innerWidth,
        canvasHeight = window.innerHeight,
        svgCanvas = d3.select('svg#canvas')
            .attr('width', canvasWidth)
            .attr('height', canvasHeight);

    const forceSim = d3_force.forceSimulation()
        .alphaDecay(0)
        .velocityDecay(0)
        .on('tick', particleDigest)
        .force('bounce', d3_force.forceBounce()
            .radius(d => d.r)
        )
        .force('container', d3_force.forceSurface()
            .surfaces([
                {from: {x:0,y:0}, to: {x:0,y:canvasHeight}},
                {from: {x:0,y:canvasHeight}, to: {x:canvasWidth,y:canvasHeight}},
                {from: {x:canvasWidth,y:canvasHeight}, to: {x:canvasWidth,y:0}},
                {from: {x:canvasWidth,y:0}, to: {x:0,y:0}}
            ])
            .oneWay(true)
            .radius(d => d.r)
        );

    // Init particles
    onDensityChange(INIT_DENSITY);

    // Event handlers
    function onDensityChange(density) {
        const newNodes = genNodes(density);
        // d3.select('#numparticles-val').text(newNodes.length);
        // d3.select('#density-control').attr('defaultValue', density);
        forceSim.nodes(newNodes);
    }

    function onElasticityChange(elasticity) {
        // d3.select('#elasticity-val').text(elasticity);
        // forceSim.force('bounce').elasticity(elasticity);
        // forceSim.force('container').elasticity(elasticity);
    }

    //

    function genNodes(density) {
        const numParticles = Math.round(canvasWidth * canvasHeight * density),
            existingParticles = forceSim.nodes();

        // Trim
        if (numParticles < existingParticles.length) {
            return existingParticles.slice(0, numParticles);
        }

        // Append
        return [...existingParticles, ...d3_force.range(numParticles - existingParticles.length).map(() => {
            const angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI,
                velocity = Math.random() * (PARTICLE_VELOCITY_RANGE[1] - PARTICLE_VELOCITY_RANGE[0]) + PARTICLE_VELOCITY_RANGE[0];

            return {
                x: Math.random() * canvasWidth,
                y: Math.random() * canvasHeight,
                vx: Math.cos(angle) * velocity,
                vy: Math.sin(angle) * velocity,
                r: Math.round(Math.random() * (PARTICLE_RADIUS_RANGE[1] - PARTICLE_RADIUS_RANGE[0]) + PARTICLE_RADIUS_RANGE[0])
            }
        })];
    }

    function particleDigest() {
        let particle = svgCanvas.selectAll('circle.particle').data(forceSim.nodes().map(hardLimit));

        particle.exit().remove();

        particle.merge(
            particle.enter().append('circle')
                .classed('particle', true)
                .attr('r', d=>d.r)
                .attr('fill', 'darkslategrey')
        )
            .attr('cx', d => d.x)
            .attr('cy', d => d.y);
    }

    function hardLimit(node) {
        // Keep in canvas
        node.x = Math.max(node.r, Math.min(canvasWidth-node.r, node.x));
        node.y = Math.max(node.r, Math.min(canvasHeight-node.r, node.y));
        return node;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <svg id="canvas"></svg>
      <div id="controls"></div>
      <div className='boxed-view'>
        {/* D3 background goes here */}
        {/* <svg className='boxed-view'></svg> */}
        <div className='boxed-view__box'>
          <h1>Login</h1>
          {this.state.error ? <p>{this.state.error}</p> : undefined}
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} className='boxed-view__form'>
            <input type="text" name='username' placeholder="Josiah Carberry" ref='username'/>
            <input type="password" name='password' ref='password'/>
            <button className='button'>Let's Go</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't know that [d3-force-bounce](https://github.com/vasturiano/d3-force-bounce) and [d3-force-surface](https://github.com/vasturiano/d3-force-surface) existed. They're both npm packages and are default exports. The methods `d3.forceBounce()` and `d3.forceSurface()` are methods of `d3ForceBounce` and `d3ForceSurface`, not d3. Finally, I forgot to call `renderAnimation()` in the JSX.